# Accessibility and elderly people: Google backups preventing deletions by "helping" users

Tags: gmail, google-account, google, accessibility, inbox-by-gmail

I have a disability and the person I share a home with helps me carry out since daily tasks every day. In order to enable this, I give this person my phone's password and get this person to manage several things on my behalf on my phone.

However, sometimes this person deletes my files. I haven't managed to convince this person not to do this. The excuse they use is often that what I write is stuff against this person or stuff that is a waste of time or of no importance.

In order to prevent me from losing my stuff, I would like to at least be able to back up my Google keep notes, and perhaps my Google drive stuff, to another Google account, such that only I have the password to this account.

However, I don't know whether there's an easy way to transfer everything to another account leaving what's there in place.

I have started emailing myself my WhatsApp conversations so that they don't get deleted, but sometimes stuff from my Google mail is deleted as well, and I would like to copy that to a second account as well.

It would be nice if Google offered another no-delete mirroring account.

How can I achieve what I am looking for.

I am sure there are order lone people with disabilities or old people out there who share this very same problem.

It would be nice if there were a way to do what I'm looking for, perhaps even a way backed up by Google.

I am using Google services on my Android phone. If this post is more suited for Super User stack exchange, then please migrate my post.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you identify what tasks require giving your caretaker your unlocked phone. Realize that once you hand over an unlocked phone, that person is YOU the phone owner. Of course people do this all the time for group photos using a device that probably contains a person's conversations, financial data, etc. You should identify what phone/OS version you are using as secondary/restricted accounts may be possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but [dfndr antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psafe.msuite&hl=pt_BR&gl=US) has a app lock feature. With this, you can choose some apps (let's say, whatsapp and  your private e-mail) and put a different password/unlocking code, blocking the access from undesired users. I usually use it for banks - If my phone gets robbed, it is at least another step the thief needs to breach to reach out my money - but you can assign any app to it.

This is [their page, on how to add apps to the app lock](https://www.psafe.com/help/docs/how-do-i-lock-unlock-certain-apps-with-dfndr-performances-applock/). I hope it helps you.

Also, I found [this other app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20lock&c=apps) which seems to do the same thing - without having a whole antivirus attached to it. I didn't use it, but it seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your phone supports setting up multiple users. If that's so — you can setup a different user account with different password and install only the needed applications there. Then, the new account's password is shared with that person, and your main one is kept secret.

The other way is "app pinning". On some devices, you can enable this feature which lets you pin the application to the screen — it will disallow quitting or minimizing the application until the password is entered. This way, you can open the app yourself, pin it, and give it to the person. This way, you can keep your password a secret and don't allow the person to do anything other than what you asked for.

In the end, I believe you should really insist on that person not invading your life this way — it is toxic and destructive.